# Are the 2 terminals of an incandescent bulb lamp equivalent?

Tags: terminal, incandescent

Compared to a resistor, which has 2 equivalent terminals, does an incandescent bulb lamp also have equivalent terminals?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An incandescent bulb is essentially just a resistor (albeit with a more complicated behavior due to the fact that it heats up and cools down much more than a conventional resistor), so it can have identical terminals. Whether it *does* have identical terminals is dependent on the particular implementation, and is more of an engineering matter.

Comment: Just want to note that most 120V or 240V bulbs do indeed have different terminals, not because the bulb needs it, but because the socket needs it.  Neutral, which is tied to ground at the breaker box, is arranged to be much easier to touch by accident than Hot.  Of course, not all wiring systems work like this, but you get the idea.

Comment: @AaronD  Bayonet Cap (BC) lamps, widely used in the UK, have completely interchangeable terminals.  You can take the lamp out, rotate it by 180 degrees, and plug it back in again with the terminals reversed.  The lamp doesn't care.